# Materialize.css Swipe right to open menu

Tags: meteor, swipe, material-design, materialize

I know [Materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/) has an option to swipe left to dismiss the open sidemenu, but is it possible to open the menu by swiping right as found in most android phones.

I have a meteor.js implementation for a android app and would want to know if such a feature offered out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible right [out of the box](http://materializecss.com/mobile.html):

[image]

Just [initialize the plugin](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html#options) like this:

```
// Initialize collapse button
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

#### [Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ERtNi8yru4DfojXErCsx?p=preview)

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
</nav>
```

For testing, just enable emulation in the chrome developer tools, reload the page, and swipe in from the edge.